# Accessing a cell in a pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex loses type information

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

When I create a pandas `DataFrame` with `MultiIndex`, accessing a single cell loses type information:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame([{"a":1.0,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4}]).set_index(["c","d"])
```

`df2.dtypes` is

```py
a    float64
b      int64
dtype: object
```

but `df2.loc[(3,4),"b"]` returns `2.0` of type `numpy.float64` instead of `2` of type `numpy.int64`.

Cf.

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame([{"a":1.0,"b":2,"c":3}]).set_index("c")
```

where `df1.loc[3,"b"]` returns `2` of type `numpy.int64` .

**Is this a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/41369) or am I doing something wrong?**

**NB**: `at` (used instead of `loc`) returns the value of the correct type for both `df1` and `df2`.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion - possible, but not nice:

```
a = df2.loc[[(3,4)],"b"].iat[0]
print (a)
2
```

Comment: Yes, this uses the same technique as in your [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67436730/850781). It creates an intermediate 1-element Series. However, it does not answer the question: **Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?**.

Comment: @sds - I think here bug.